# Absolute path to stylesheet_dir/images/my_img.jpg does not work?

Tags: jquery, images

I am manipulating an img element in functions.php using jQuery by changing the src attr on hover. How do I make so the absolute path works? Currently, when I view the image directly in the browser it brings me to 404 page. Relative path doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always start every theme w/ some constants

`
define('THEME', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'));
//or you could use this one:
//define('THEME', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());

define('IMAGES', THEME . '/images');
`

and some others, but the point is that at any place in my code i can point to my theme's image folder

`img src = "<?php echo IMAGES . '/image.png';?>"`

Comment: Yah that's another way of getting the relative path. But like I said it doesn't work. But if I host the image in another site and use their link, the img displays fine. Maybe it's because of thematic theme? I know I could just switch to another theme to find out but I don't want to break things as of now.

Comment: doubt it is a thematic issue, i use this w/ thematic all the time.  should produce a link like http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/image.png which isn't a relative link.  

from codex on get_bloginfo
'stylesheet_directory' - Returns the stylesheet directory URL of the active theme. (Was a local path in earlier WordPress versions.) Consider using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead.

so you could 
define('THEME', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());

what do you get in your markup (view source) for the image source. that is more telling than  "it doesn't work"

Comment: You are right it works! Maybe I was too sleepy yesterday! :-) Now the problem I am facing is how to do that with jQuery but that's a different question already. Thanks!

Comment: if you inject your jquery in the header or footer you can still process the php.  if you have it in a js file that won't work.  >>>

var src = "<?php echo IMAGES . '/image.png';?>"